# How to use grabcut algorithm using OpenCV with ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, opencv

I want to create **grabcut** algorithm for image processing but i can't find perfect implementation .I have tried so many code but i cant found solution.

is there any example for **Grabcut** in **openCV**.So I can implement in my application.?

Comment: I am iphone developer and developing application to edit Image using OpenCV.So please reply fast....

Answer (score 2):

You can check this tutorial here.

[grabcut algorithm](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/grabcut.cpp)

People reply to problems independently. Please do not demand to reply fast. Googling the problem will get you some hints.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

See this repository.
It is demo application using GrabCut

https://github.com/naver/grabcutIOS

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.